# firebase realtime database does not work on mobile but is working on emulator

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

```
binding.btSave.setOnClickListener {
        val firstName = binding.etFirstName.text.toString()
        val lastName = binding.etLastName.text.toString()
        val age = binding.etAge.text.toString()
        val userName = binding.etUserName.text.toString()

        if (firstName.isNotEmpty() && age.isNotEmpty() && lastName.isNotEmpty() && userName.isNotEmpty()) {

            try {

                database =
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("My Url")
                        .getReference("Users")

                val users = User(firstName, lastName, age, userName)

                database.child(userName).setValue(users).addOnSuccessListener {

                    binding.etAge.text.clear()
                    binding.etFirstName.text.clear()
                    binding.etLastName.text.clear()
                    binding.etUserName.text.clear()

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }.addOnFailureListener {

                    Toast.makeText(this, it.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                }

            } catch (e: Exception) {

                Toast.makeText(this, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            } finally {
                Toast.makeText(this, "finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        }
    }
```

when I click the button it goes directly to "finally" of try catch in mobile but in emulator is ok
and I give permission of internet and access network state to the app also the app is working for  Authentication well

what should I do ??

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: its just does not work on my cellphone that it I dont have any error by the way I connecting to firebase from Iran @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

Did you add permissions to access the internet in Manifest file?
Debugger is working without this permissions, but when you want to build "production" application, it requires this permissions to work.

You need to add those 2 lines:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

reference:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting

Comment: yes I added these permission

Answer (score 0):

Posting this for later reference. I also faced the same issue.

What worked for me is deleting the `google-services.json` file I had in the project & re-downloading it from the console